# How do I set up Moq so that I can unit test adding multiple groups and clients in SignalR?

Tags: signalr, moq, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I've been working on coming with a SignalR Unit testing framework using Moq.
I have been able things to get reasonably well with the 1 group - 1 client (connection) scenario.

How do I set up Moq so I can:

1) Add/remove multiple clients from the same group?

2) Add/remove multiple groups on the same mocked hub?

I'm relatively new to the world of Moq and SignalR combination.

Thanks in advance,
JohnB

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example testing adding a client to multipe groups using Moq and xUnit.net:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task MyHubAddsConnectionToTheCorrectGroups()
{
    // Arrange
    var groupManagerMock = new Mock<IGroupManager>();
    var connectionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var groupsJoined = new List<string>();

    groupManagerMock.Setup(g => g.Add(connectionId, It.IsAny<string>()))
                    .Returns(Task.FromResult<object>(null))
                    .Callback<string, string>((cid, groupToJoin) =>
                        groupsJoined.Add(groupToJoin));

    var myHub = new MyHub();
    myHub.Groups = groupManagerMock.Object;
    myHub.Context = new HubCallerContext(request: null,
                                         connectionId: connectionId);

    // Act
    await myHub.AddToGroups();

    // Assert
    groupManagerMock.VerifyAll();
    Assert.Equal(3, groupsJoined.Count);
    Assert.Contains("group1", groupsJoined);
    Assert.Contains("group2", groupsJoined);
    Assert.Contains("group3", groupsJoined);
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public async Task AddToGroups()
    {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "group1");
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "group2");
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "group3");
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to define a `Callback` along with your `Setup` that stores arguments important to your test inside a collection. You can then use the collection verify that the method you mocked was called the right number of times with the right arguments. I don't verify the order of the calls to `Groups.Add` in my example test, but you can test that as well.

This pattern extends pretty trivially to testing the adding/removing of multiple clients. Basically, you would just need a second collection to store the `connectionId` arguments passed to `Groups.Add`.